# How come my javascript code is not working, even though it works on the website JSFiddle? Button editing value of textbox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to edit the value of a textbox, based on button click.
I found some code that works on JSFiddle but for some reason it doesn't work inside of my PHP file.

This is how I've transferred to my file, adding script tag:

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" id="b1" value="1" />


<script>
$('#b1').click(
    function(){
        $('#input').val($('#input').val()+$(this).val());
    }
);
</script>
```

This is the program inside of JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mE6CX/

When I am running the code on my server the html appears, but there's no interaction.

Comment: are there any errors in your console? Did you link jQuery? Are you running this code once the DOM has loaded?

Comment: thanks for the reply. There aren't any errors in my console. I don't think I linked jQuery so I added <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> just now. but it still doesn't work. maybe that's a wrong link.

Comment: The link looks fine (make sure you include the closing `</script>` tag as well). What if you wrap your code in the onload function like so: http://jsfiddle.net/8qjybcgL/1/

Comment: k. wow interesting. I am trying to do this, it's still not doing any thing. I'm thinking maybe this is an old version of JS code, I don't know. my webpage seems to be reacting to changes so who knows.

Comment: oh wow i just resolved it

Comment: the problem was that i needed to have two different script tags one for the linking and the other for the code. thanks a lot for the help. :)